# Do i need to set default gateway to domain controler or no when i am in same subnet?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

Heloo to all,

i dont know this

Do i need to set default gateway to users for domain controler autentification or no when they are in same subnet as domain controler except dns?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to set a gateway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to set a gateway if you want traffic to be routed. Traffic on the same subnet does not need to be routed.

That said, if you don't set a gateway, it won't be able to communicate outside of the subnet, so your clients using it for DNS won't be able to use it as a recursive resolver.

Comment: Thank you @MDMarra for answer. So basically i can set to users default gateway of my router for internet acces and dns to point on windows server computer which is runing dc,ad,dhcp, dns services am i correct ?

Comment: Yes, that's a standard config.